# JMX Monitoring on a Weblogic Cluster, how to monitor java.lang space

Tags: weblogic, jmx

On a remote Weblogic Cluster, I would access to each size of the Non Heap memory of each instance of my cluster.

I'm connected to my admin server with a url such as this one:
service:jmx:t3://acetp-env-admin:9091/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime

How could I access to java.lang jmx package of each instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service url you have will let you connect to the MBean server that Weblogic is exposing. This is for control over services weblogic provides but not core JVM mbeans. You need to connect to the Platform MBean server - directly to the JVM. That's why you're not seeing java.lang.

Check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/mxbeans.html

Comment: ok, that's what I supposed! No miracle method to register the java.lang.* in mean